# Binding progress bar to a service in JavaFX

Tags: service, javafx, binding, progress-bar

I am attempting to bind a progress bar to the progress of a service. I have created the progress bar in scene builder, and have attempted the below code. But the progress bar continually runs, and does not represent the service it is connected to. It should be running while the service is running, and representing the data being downloaded. How do I bind the progress bar to represent the service I have created.

```
@FXML
private ProgressBar ProgressBar;
service.start();
ProgressBar.progressProperty().bind(service.workDoneProperty());
```

Answer (score 5):

You should bind ProgressBar's `progressProperty()` to Service's `progressProperty()` and not to its workDoneProperty i.e.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        StackPane root = new StackPane(progressBar);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        Service service = new Service() {
            @Override
            protected Task createTask() {
                return new Task() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object call() throws Exception {
                        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
                            updateProgress(i, 100);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
        service.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ItachiUchiha , I have tried the 'service.progressProperty()' but the progress bar still continues to run, after the service has finished. Do I need to set the value of the progress bar to zero, before binding it to the service?

Comment: I think there is a problem with your implementation. Can you add more details to your question on how did you implement it?

Comment: I have two separate threads, one that gets the data using a task and service, and another that constructs the GUI, and has some functionality. I have instantiated a new instance of the task class in my main thread

Comment: 'private DashService service;' and I am attempting to bind it to the progress bar

Comment: I think you don't need two different threads for fetching data and updating the GUI. Both the things can be easily handled by Task.

Comment: But if your service has not a loop.

Comment: works like a charm! I tried with Task but it kept failing as in the task will not execute concurrently with the progress indicator. Service saved the day!